# Laravel - Show "threads" only to users who are the recipients of the thread

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

A user can only view and post on a thread that the user is a "recipient" of. I have explained it in more detailed down below.

My tables structure:

`threads` table: `user_id`, `subject`, `recipients` (contains serialized array of users)

`messages` table: `thread_id`, `user_id`, `body`

`participants` table: `thread_id`, `user_id`, `read_at`, `deleted_at`

So what I want is a way to show all threads that the user is a recipient of. And if they have deleted the thread (each time a thread is created, the participants table is populated by each recipient). For instance, if a thread has 3 recipients, 3 rows will be created in the `participants` table with their user ID. And there they have an option to delete the thread to not see it when they are viewing all threads that "belongs" to them.

I do not know how I can figure out a way to show threads to users who are the recipients of the threads. Please help me tackle this issue. Thanks!

I tried the following code but no luck.

```
    $threads = Thread::all();
    $participant = Participant::where(['user_id' => uid()])->get();
    foreach ($threads as $thread) {
       $recipients = unserialize($thread->recipients);
        if (in_array(uid(), $recipients) || $thread->user_id == uid()) {
           $messages = (object)Participant::where(['user_id' => uid(), 'thread_id' => $thread->id])->paginate(10);
        }
    }
```

Demo:

A thread has been created:

The recipients' user_id's are: 4, 7, 8.

`threads` table:

```
id  | user_id | subject | recipients
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |       1 | Hello   | a:1:{s:7:"user_id";a:3:{i:0;i:4;i:1;i:7;i:2;i:8;}}
```

`messages` table:

```
id  | user_id | thread_id | body
--------------------------------------------
1   |       1 |         1 | How you doing?
```

`participants` table:

```
id  | user_id | thread_id | read_at
--------------------------------------------
1   |       1 |         1 | 2016-04-13 00:03:23
--------------------------------------------
1   |       4 |         1 | NULL
--------------------------------------------
1   |       7 |         1 | NULL
--------------------------------------------
1   |       8 |         1 | NULL
```

Comment: Why are you storing a serialized array in the database? You should be normalizing the `threads` table and move those `recipients` values to a separate table, that way you can use relationships.

Comment: Sorry, can you please explain a bit more? If I create a new table called, say, `recipients`, what would the columns be and what could the column be in the `threads` table to be able to use relationships?

Comment: Since you want to create a relationship between a thread entry and a user entry and this relationship would be [**many-to-many**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), then the `recipients` table (or alternatively called `users_thread` if you want Eloquent relationships to work out of the box) should have a `thread_id` and a `user_id`. The `thread_id` would be referencing the `id` column on the `threads` table and the `user_id` is referencing `id` on a `users` table (which I'm guessing you have although you didn't specify).

Comment: Wouldn't that be the participants table that I already have? Thank you so much for your response.